# Update a database table based on the outcome of the result of the update

Tags: mysql, sql, database, sql-update

I want up update a column salaries by 10% unless the salary becomes greater that 95,000 ... If it is, then I wan to update by 3 % instead.

Any idea how I can get this done?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried using CASE statements in your UPDATE statement

```
UPDATE YOURTABLE
SET salaries = CASE
                   WHEN (salaries * 1.1) > 95000 THEN (salaries * 1.03)
                   ELSE (saleries * 1.1)
               END
```